# How can I increase movement speed

Tags: mods, fallout

Is there  a command or hack in the original Fallout game to increase the run speed?  Sometimes navigating between areas of map locations (Hub, Necropolis, etc) is a bit of a drag.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Sfall](https://github.com/Sduibek/sfall_1) mod for Fallout 1 which increases movement and combat speed.

More info [here](http://ton-hur.mbnet.fi/files/fallout/sfall1_readme.txt).

> **Increase movement and combat speed to up to 10x normal.**